# SSMS error: Subquery returned more than 1 value... but there is no subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

The full error message is this one:  Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression. Everything I can find on it just says "yeah, just use TOP 1 and it'll be fine," only I don't even have a subquery or a select statement.

Here's the query:

```
update f
set f.new_monthnumber = datediff(mm, dateadd(dd, dbo.ufn_GetDaysInMonth(a.new_opendate) -   16, a.new_opendate), f.new_submit_date) + 1
from FilteredAccount a 
    left outer join FilteredNew_Financials f on f.new_name = a.accountnumber
where f.new_monthnumber is null
```

ufn_GetDaysInMonth is a user-defined function that analyzes the date passed to it and does not query the database at all, and in any case I've confirmed that it is not the cause of the error by running the query without it.

Anyone know what the heck is going on here?

Comment: Hi, if your remove completely the nested datediff on the right of the assignment it works right?

Comment: Just tried it, and actually, no it doesn't.

Comment: but if you remove the whole datediff and the join and you only operate on the table f it should work right? For what I remember SQL 2005 still does not like update commands with such structure, while SQL 2008 does with no problem.

Comment: I have this same issue. Not sure why it was voted into the negative. Bumped you back up to zero.

Answer (score 1):

Given that to write this query I would have swapped the tables and used an inner join, in order to have "FilteredNew_Financials" in both UPDATE and FROM clauses, pheraps there is a 1-to-n cardinality between the two tables on the join condition... maybe you have some dirty data in tables?
Are you sure "new_name" and "accountnumber" are primary and foreign keys (at least logically, if not structurally)?

Comment: at a guess, the error is thrown when the query driving the UPDATE tries to update the same row multiple times. I'm guessing the implementation of UPDATE...FROM reuses some of the subquery machinery.

Comment: yeah, that was what i meant ;)

Comment: @araqnid - that was already covered in point 3 of my answer. The OP said this did not raise an error. Unless the OP divulges the execution plan I guess we will never know.

Comment: @martin: huh? this: `The full error message is this one: Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression` is not an error?

Comment: @BertuPG - If you look at point 3 of my answer you will see that I set up a test scenario testing exactly this. The OP said **that test scenario** did not raise an error. (They might be getting a different plan for their actual query in which this **does** cause a problem however unless you can produce a test scenario that replicates this we have no means of knowing without the OP's input)

Comment: @martin: Anyway, if correctly remember, araqnid's comment to my answer was posted before you edited your answer to add 3th point. Also, here we were discussing the original scenario, not others.

Comment: @BertuPG - You remember entirely incorrectly. I had already made the point before this answer was posted as the edit history shows! My answer is as far as is possible without the UDF definition exactly the same as the original scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I would have written the query slightly differenty:

```
update FilteredNew_Financials
set new_monthnumber = datediff(mm, dateadd(dd, dbo.ufn_GetDaysInMonth(a.new_opendate) -   16, a.new_opendate), f.new_submit_date) + 1
from FilteredAccount a 
    left outer join FilteredNew_Financials f on f.new_name = a.accountnumber
where f.new_monthnumber is null
```

Does that work?

Comment: Does FilteredNew_Financials have a primary key?

Comment: Yes. If it helps, this is an MSCRM database.